# Morph Targets Normal adding math

Tags: vectors

I am trying to verify that if I have my `inNormal` and some `N` amount of morph normals that I would want to do something such as

```
outNormal = vec3(inNormal);
outNormal += morphNormal0 * morphWeight0;
outNormal += morphNormal1 * morphWeight1;
...
outNormal += morphNormalN * morphWeightN;
```

This seems to work for me (don't have a ground truth to compare) so I wanted to test it in Three.js knowing it would have an established method and I see [they use](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/morphnormal_vertex.glsl)

```
objectNormal += ( morphNormal0 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
objectNormal += ( morphNormal1 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
objectNormal += ( morphNormal2 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
objectNormal += ( morphNormal3 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
```

So now I am wondering how that math works out as it doesn't work for me. Both methods end up multiplying it by a `normalMatrix`so not sure what would be different.

**edit**: Assuming both are loading in glTF 2.0 models

Comment: In your method, is morphNormalN a delta or the actual normal to morph towards?

Comment: @bram0101 the spec says "deviations in the Morph Target" and looking at the data it looks like morphNormal0 a delta, not the "new normal" of the morph target position

Comment: Actually I realized I never checked if they altered the morphNormals prior to this

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that, in the second example, the morphNormals are targets while in in the first they are deltas.

This explains the difference in math used between the two pieces of code.